# How does a 3rd party API open a window?

Tags: python, operating-system, native

This question has been on my mind for a while. If I use a 3d party API in Python such as Kivy or TKinter I know there must be a call to the OS to open a native window but I can't find any info on this. When I search I only get tutorials on how to use them to create a gui. If anyone can help me track down the information I'd be very grateful.